# @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@2.3.2: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

I want to create react app using comand `npx create-react-app ...` when I was running this command in terminal it showed this error:

```
@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@2.3.2: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^8.10.0 || ^10.13.0 || >=11.10.1". Got "10.2.1"
```

How to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version (11.x) <---------  If we need an older version
version (12.x)
version (14.x)

Solution:

1. Uninstall existing nodejs
2. Install nodejs (`LTS version`) from https://nodejs.org/en/

Comment: If you want to use multiple versions of node at your machine at the same time use the `nvm` node version manager. https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Comment: True. For windows, now I used `nvm`.

Answer (score 4):

> Expected version "^8.10.0 || ^10.13.0 || >=11.10.1". Got "10.2.1"

Your nodejs version is very old and has known security bugs. Update to the latest version of a supported release.